# Don't get connection to HSQLDB database

Tags: database-connection, hsqldb

I have already existed database.  When I test my connection, I get this exception

```
java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: invalid authorization specification: SA
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at libraryapp.AppConnect.getConnection(AppConnect.java:17)
at libraryapp.TestAppConnection.main(TestAppConnection.java:7)
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: invalid authorization specification: SA
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.rights.User.checkPassword(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.rights.UserManager.getUser(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Database.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.newSession(Unknown Source)
```

My connection class

```
public class AppConnect {
    private static final String url ="jdbc:hsqldb:file:src/main/resources/db/library";
    private static final String driver ="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver";
    private static final String user = "SA";
    private static final String password = " ";

    public Connection getConnection() {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            connection.setAutoCommit(true);
            System.out.println("Good connection");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Failed to establish the connection :(");
        }
        return connection;
    }
}
```

In pom.xml i have this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

If i change path to non-existent database, it's create and connect

Answer (score 0):

The error means your connection URL finds the database but the combination of username and password is not correct.

The password you are using is a space, but the default password for a database is the empty string. Try changing it to:

```
  private static final String password = "";
```

If that doesn't work, you need to find out what you originally used as username and password when you created the database.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thank you. The problem was in space. But if String doesn't have even space, it's not null, and what does assign to the variable?

Comment: The zero-length string is assigned to the variable and used as password.